# PySpark: NULL values in Join 2nd dataframe should match

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, databricks

I have a requirement if a matching `df2` has a null value it should match. Spark doesn't match rows with null by default.

`df1`:

```
ID  Name    City    EMAIL
1   John    City A  a@gmail.com
2   Mist    City B  b@gmail.com
3   Danny   City C  c@gmail.com
```

`df2`:

```
ID  Name    City    EMAIL
1   John    City A  d@gmail.com
2   null    City B  e@gmail.com
3   Danny   City C  f@gmail.com
```

```py
df3 = df1.join(df2, on=["ID", "NAME", "CITY"]) 
display(df3)
```

Spark Output:

```
ID  Name    City    EMAIL   EMAIL
1   John    City A  a@gmail.com d@gmail.com
3   Danny   City C  c@gmail.com f@gmail.com
```

Expected Output:

```
ID  Name    City    EMAIL           EMAIL
1   John    City A  a@gmail.com d@gmail.com
2   Mist    City B  b@gmail.com e@gmail.com
3   Danny   City C  c@gmail.com f@gmail.com
```

As shown above, since `ID` and `CITY` match and `NAME` have null values, the join should match and give the expected result.

And I can't remove `NAME` on the joining column it should match `NAME`, just if `NAME` is null then those columns also should match.

Kindly help.

Comment: Do `df1.Name` can also contain Nulls?

Comment: no only df2.name can contain Nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df3 = df1.join(
    df2, 
    on=[
        df1.ID == df2.ID, 
        df1.City == df2.City, 
        (df1.Name == df2.Name) | df2.Name.isNull()
    ]
).select(df1.ID, df1.Name, df1.City, df1.EMAIL, df2.EMAIL)
df3.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+------+-----------+-----------+
| ID| Name|  City|      EMAIL|      EMAIL|
+---+-----+------+-----------+-----------+
|  1| John|City A|a@gmail.com|d@gmail.com|
|  2| Mist|City B|b@gmail.com|e@gmail.com|
|  3|Danny|City C|c@gmail.com|f@gmail.com|
+---+-----+------+-----------+-----------+
```